# Full Text Search for Multiple tables in SQl Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I need to implement Full text search across tables.

what are the different options.

Comment: Are you indexing binary data (word docs etc) or string data in tables ?

Comment: Some more specific information .. even an example table with example data and some expected results. Question to vauge.

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to Full Text index and indexed view of the tables